# WBadmin script to backup System State into another partition failed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, wbadmin

I tried numerous time but it is still failed like the following script on cmd prompt.

Is there any way to create automated script to backup system state on my Windows Server 2008 using WBAdmin into D drive inside a directory ?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

> C:\Users\Administrator>wbadmin START
>   SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP
>   -backuptarget:D:\Admin\Backup wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool (C) Copyright 2004 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Starting System State Backup
>   [12/02/2011 4:22 AM] Retrieving volume
>   information...
>
> This would backup the system state
>   from volume(s) SYS(C:) to
>   D:\Admin\Backup. Do you want to start
>   the backup operation? [Y] Yes [N] No Y
>
> ERROR - Specified backup location
>   could not be found.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>wbadmin START
>   SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP
>   -backuptarget:D:\Admin wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool (C) Copyright
>   2004 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Starting System State Backup
>   [12/02/2011 4:22 AM] Retrieving volume
>   information...
>
> This would backup the system state
>   from volume(s) SYS(C:) to D:\Admin. Do
>   you want to start the backup
>   operation? [Y] Yes [N] No Y
>
> ERROR - Specified backup location
>   could not be found.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>wbadmin START
>   SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP
>   -backuptarget:"D:\Admin\Backup" -quiet wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
>   (C) Copyright 2004 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Starting System State Backup
>   [12/02/2011 4:23 AM] Retrieving volume
>   information...
>
> This would backup the system state
>   from volume(s) SYS(C:) to
>   D:\Admin\Backup.
>
> ERROR - Specified backup location
>   could not be found.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>wbadmin START
>   SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backuptarget:D:\
>   -quiet wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool (C) Copyright 2004
>   Microsoft Corp.
>
> Starting System State Backup
>   [12/02/2011 4:23 AM] Retrieving volume
>   information...
>
> This would backup the system state
>   from volume(s) SYS(C:) to D:.
>
> ERROR - Specified backup location
>   could not be found.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>

Comment: Have you created this folder and made sure it has the correct permissions: D:\Admin\Backup

Comment: Yes I am the administrator of the local server (not domain joined yet).

Comment: Are you running Command Prompt as an administrator?

Comment: yes i am the local admin of this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the "\" cause the problem, the final command is:

**C:\Users\Administrator>wbadmin START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backuptarget:D:** without the back slash.